# Next Js and axios instance with base url not working

Tags: rest, next.js, axios

I have created an axios instance like so for making api request to external server. My project contains a rest api server built with express js, frontend with next js. In dev it all works fine but after publishing to vercel all call to rest server looks like this

> > https://sandbox.{domain}.com/api.sandbox..com

but it should be

> > https://api.sandbox.{domain}.com

axios config

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${API_ROOT}/v1`,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

my next.config.js looks like this

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "images.unsplash.com",
      "images.pexels.com",
    ],
  },
  
};
```

I don't really where to look

I tried putting the domain directly as axios baseUrl but did not work.